# Creating a list from a .txt file to write on excel

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to create a list from a large series of data I have on a .txt file.
I want to proccess them through excel and show I have been doing this to create a iterative list, that will be written in every column.However I get the error that I am not defining j.

```
import xlwt

f=open('inputfile.txt')
c=1

for lines in f:
    #split = f.split('\t')
    style0=xlwt.easyxf('font:name Times New Roman,colour black,bold on')
    wb=xlwt.Workbook()
    ws=wb.add_sheet('Database',cell_overwrite_ok=True)
    for i,row in enumerate(lines):
        ws.write(i,j,col)
        print(str(c))
        c=c+1
    wb.save('Prueba.xls')
```

Additionally I would like to ask If it would be possible to creat a single list from two lines of .txt?

Comment: Well, you don't define `j` indeed :). You define `row`.

Comment: What do YOU think j is? Python doesn't have a clue...

Comment: Also, what is the format of the text inside `inputfile.txt`?

Comment: Could you explain further what you mean by your last question? perhaps show what your two lines of text would look like in the input file, and what you would like them to look like on the output?

Answer (score 0):

*You have not defined variable **j and col** (instead you defined extra variable row which is unused here), you have to define the variable.*

```
  for i,row in enumerate(lines):
```

You have to define j here `for i,j, col in enumerate(lines):`

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are indeed, not defining `j`.

You also have not defined `col` either.

perhaps you meant something like:

```
import xlwt

f=open('inputfile.txt')
c=1

for lines in f:
    #split = f.split('\t')
    style0=xlwt.easyxf('font:name Times New Roman,colour black,bold on')
    wb=xlwt.Workbook()
    ws=wb.add_sheet('Database',cell_overwrite_ok=True)
    for i,j in enumerate(lines):  # change to define j
        ws.write(i,j,c)           # change to use c instead of col
        print(str(c))
        c=c+1
    wb.save('Prueba.xls')
```

But this still doesn't make a ton of sense to me as i imagine you are looking for 2D output.

Another thing is when you iterate through a file i.e. `for line in file` you will be iterating through each line already so the second loop seems to either be mislabeled or misunderstood.

Perhaps you meant:

```
import xlwt

f=open('inputfile.txt')
c=1

style0=xlwt.easyxf('font:name Times New Roman,colour black,bold on')
wb=xlwt.Workbook()
ws=wb.add_sheet('Database',cell_overwrite_ok=True)

for row_num,lines in f:
    for col_num,entry in enumerate(lines.split('\t')):
        ws.write(row_num,col_num,entry)
        print(str(c))
        c=c+1
    wb.save('Prueba.xls')

f.close() # Make sure you close your files!
```

You need to also make sure you `close` your file, i.e. `file.close()` when you're finished with it.

I would suggest a bit of an overhaul

My guess going out on a limb from your commented out portion of code, you are dealing with a tab delimited text file?  In which case I would reccommend the following revisions:

```
import xlwt

with open('inputfile.txt') as f:
    c=1
    wb=xlwt.Workbook()
    style0=xlwt.easyxf('font:name Times New Roman,colour black,bold on')
    ws=wb.add_sheet('Database',cell_overwrite_ok=True)
    for i,line in f:
        for j,entry in line.split('\t'):
            ws.write(i,j,entry)                        # change to use c instead of col
            print(str(c))
            c=c+1
    wb.save('Prueba.xls')
```

This will now create a text tab delimited translation to excel using `xlwt`.

My changes:

1. Switch to the `with open('file','r') as f:` syntax, a little more pythonic and handles closing the file for you which is missing from your provided code.
2. Organizing your initialization to take place outside the loop and not in it.
3. Then iterate through the lines, and subsequently through the tab delimited entries, translating them to row and column coordinates respectively when placing the values in the excel file.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're eventually trying to get to here:

```
import xlwt

f=open('inputfile.txt')
style0=xlwt.easyxf('font:name Times New Roman,colour black,bold on')
wb=xlwt.Workbook()
ws=wb.add_sheet('Database',cell_overwrite_ok=True)


c=0
for lines in f:
    split = f.split('\t')
    for i,val in enumerate(split):
        ws.write(i,c,val)
        c=c+1

wb.save('Prueba.xls')
```

this assumes ws.write expects a row index (and you **will** want to verify that), followed by a column index, followed by the value to write to that cell.  this code will put each line from inputfile.txt in a separate column.  if you want each line from the input file to exist in separate rows, then you are looking for this solution:

```
import xlwt

f=open('inputfile.txt')
style0=xlwt.easyxf('font:name Times New Roman,colour black,bold on')
wb=xlwt.Workbook()
ws=wb.add_sheet('Database',cell_overwrite_ok=True)


row_index=0
for lines in f:
    split = f.split('\t')
    for i,val in enumerate(split):
        ws.write(row_index,i,val)
        c=c+1

wb.save('Prueba.xls')
```